# Write csv of a single number with no header

Tags: r, csv, io

To write a csv with more than one element without a header, we use for example:

```
write.table(trees, file="/tmp/trees.csv",row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, sep=",")
```

However, if I want to write a csv of `0` or `matrix(0)`, it will give the column name of `x`. Thus the `csv` looks like:

```
x
0
```

when printed in terminal. This is generated from `write.table(as.matrix(0),quote=FALSE,col.names=FALSE,row.names=FALSE)`.

How can I adjust the writing function so that the written csv is only printed as:

`0`

Comment: use `header = FALSE`?

Comment: @thijsvandenbergh If this actually works I recommend you post an answer.

Comment: @thijs Doesn't work `Error in write.table(0, header = FALSE, col.names = NA, sep = ",", dec = ".",  : 
  unused argument (header = FALSE)
`

Comment: if i use `row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE` i get a file with only your requested `0` in it...

Answer (score 0):

use `?write` as in :

`write(0, '/tmp/trees.txt')`.

This is strictly not a `csv` though.